# Setting a specific element of a char** array to NULL

Tags: c, arrays

I am attempting to set the last element in a second `char **` array to `NULL` after I encounter a specific char in the first array.

```
int test(char ** args){
   char ** chmd1;
   for(int i = 0; args[i] != NULL; ++i){
     if(!strncmp(args[i], "<", 1)){
        chmd1[i] = NULL;
        break;
     }
     chmd1[i] = args[i];
   }

   for(int i = 0; chmd1[i] != NULL; ++i){
      printf("%s", chmd1[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This code segfaults as the second for loop goes on for more iterations past where the `NULL` should be.

I want to be able to be able to do this just by manipulating pointers and not using any mallocs, but I'm completely stuck.

Comment: you need to allocate some memory for chmd1 before you start assigning pointers to it

Comment: also, you need to null terminate chmd1 in the event that the loop reaches the end of the array without the break condition being met

Comment: char** is not an array, nor does it point to an array, nor is it an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> This code segfaults as the second for loop goes on for more iterations past where the the NULL should be.

You have not allocated memory for `chmd1` and yet you are using it like it points to valid memory.

> I want to be able to be able to do this just by manipulating pointers and not using any mallocs, but I'm completely stuck.

You can't do that. You have use `malloc` (or one of the other functions from the `malloc` group of functions: `calloc`, `realloc`) to allocate memory for `chmd1` before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmd1[i] = args[i];
```

`chmd[i]` is a pointer in 2D space and you are not allocating memory for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

allocate memory for pointer 
    char ** chmd1;

> I want to be able to be able to do this just by manipulating pointers and not using any mallocs, but I'm completely stuck.

Without allocating memory to chmd1, it will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory for `char ** chmd1;` before assigning value `NULL` (or copy elements from `args`) to any element.

It can be something like

```
 char ** chmd1 = malloc(NUMBER * sizeof(char*));
```

or even

```
 char * chmd1[NUMBER];
```

To determine `NUMBER` value find the NULL in the `args` first.

**EDIT:**

Also you can use `realloc` in your loop as:

```cpp
    char **chmd1 = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; ++i){
        chmd1 = (char**)realloc(chmd1, i * sizeof(char*) );
        if(!strncmp(argv[i], "<", 1)){
            chmd1[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        chmd1[i] = argv[i];
    }
    // then use i as size of chmd1
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < i; cnt++)
    {
          if( chmd1[i] == NULL ) ; // do something
    }
```